# For which $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ is $(4n+9)/(2n^2+7n+6)$ a terminating decimal?

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

I saw this problem [here](http://www.gute-mathe-fragen.de/90274/abbrechende-dezimalbruchentwicklung).

My approach:

Let $A = (4n+9)/(2n^2+7n+6) = \frac{6}{2n + 3} - \frac{1}{n + 2}$

If $\frac{6}{2n + 3}$ and $\frac{1}{n + 2}$ are terminating decimals, then so is $A$.

A number terminates if and only if it can be written as a ratio of the form $\frac{k}{2^m\cdot5^n}$

We know that $2\nmid2n+3$

So $2n+3=3^x\cdot5^y$ where $0\le x\le1$, $1\le y$ and $n+2=(3^x\cdot5^y+1)/2$

So we have $A = \frac{6}{3^x\cdot5^y} - \frac{2}{3^x\cdot5^y+1}$

But I don't even know if this approach makes any sense.

Comment: 1) In principle at least, the original fraction could be terminating, with neither "simple" fraction terminating; 2) You have not dealt completely with the second fraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only prime that can simultaneously divide numerator and denominator is $3$. For if an odd prime $p$ divides $4n+9$ and $2n+3$, it must divide $(4n+9)-2(2n+3)=3$. And it is easy to see that $4n+9$ and $n+2$ are relatively prime.

We first examine the case where $3$ does not simultaneously divide numerator and denominator. Then $2n+3$ must be a power of $5$. What about $n+2$? In principle it could be divisible by a power of $2$ greater than $1$. However, that would make $2n+3$ of the shape $4k+1$, which no power of $5$ can be.

So $2n+3$ is a power of $5$ and $n+2$ is a power of $2$. This is obviously impossible if $n$ is positive (it only happens if $n=-1$).

It remains to deal with the case where $3$ divides both $4n+9$ and $2n+3$. Then $3$ must divide $n$. Let $n=3m$. Then our expression becomes
$$\frac{4m+3}{(2m+1)(3m+2)}.$$
It is easy to see that $3$ cannot divide both numerator and denominator. So $2m+1$ is a power of $5$. Since $2m+1$ and $3m+2$ are relatively prime, that forces $3m+2$ to be a power of $2$. There are the obvious solutions $m=0$ (which the wording of the problem does not allow) and $m=2$. That gives the solution $n=4$.

Are there other solutions? Note that $2(3m+2)-3(2m+1)=1$. So we need to consider solutions of the exponential Diophantine equation $2^x-3\cdot 5^y=1$.  We do not know whether this equation has solutions other than the ones mentioned.

**Added:** Thanks to Gerry Myerson for pointing out that the exponential Diophantine equation has no other solutions.

**Added 2:** Zafer Cesur has pointed out that the analysis of the equation $2^x-3\cdot 5^y=1$ does not require fancy machinery.  By working modulo $3$, we can see that $x$ is even, say $x=2n$. Then the equation can be rewritten as $(2^n-1)(2^n+1)=3\cdot 5^y$. Because $2^n-1$ and $2^n+1$ are relatively prime, the only possibilities are $2^n-1=1$ and $2^n-1=3$.

Comment: There have been a bunch of papers on exponential diophantine equations, and I'd be surprised if that one hasn't been solved. Leo Alex and Lorraine Foster were among the people publishing on the topic.

Comment: Stormer found all solutions of $1+2^a3^b5^c=2^d3^e5^f$, Quelques theoremes sur l'equation de Pell $x^2-Dy^2=1$ et leurs applications, Skrifter Videnskabs-seskabet (Christiana), I, Mat. Naturv. Kl., (1897), no. 2 (48 pp.).

Comment: How is $n=4$ a solution? That yields $\frac{25}{66}$ which is not terminating.

Comment: Thanks, typo, $n=3m$ so $n=6$.

Comment: See also D H Lehmer, On a problem of Stormer, Illinois J Math 8 (1964) 57-79, available at http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256067456

Comment: Indeed, from the tables at the back of the Lehmer article, the only solutions are $4-3\times1=1$ and $16-3\times5=1$, so $(x,y)$ is $(2,0)$ or $(4,1)$.

Comment: Nice solution. It's actually elementary to solve this equation: $$2^x−3\cdot5^y=1 \Rightarrow 2^x\equiv 1 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow x=2n \Rightarrow (2^n-1)\cdot(2^n+1)=3\cdot5^y$$ which has two solutions beucase $2^n-1$ and $2^n+1$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Good. I am embarrassed!